# Seam 2.3.1 Final not working in Java 1.7

Tags: java, richfaces, jboss7.x, seam2

I have a working application built in Seam 2.3.1 Final, Java 1.6 and Jboss 7.1.1. It is working fine until now but when I tried to migrate the application to java 1.7 suddenly none of the Java classes with annotation @Name are working in the facelets pages. I am getting "Target Unreachable, identifier 'authenticator' resolved to null" when trying to login into the application. When I build my application in 1.6 and deploy to server I see this on the console - "Component: authenticator, scope: EVENT, type: JAVA_BEAN, class: org.domain.TestProject.session.Authenticator" whereas when I build the application in 1.7 and deploy it to the server I dont see this text at all in the console that mean its not even registering authenticator component.

Can anyone suggest me if there is anything else that needs to be done to make Seam work in java 1.7? Or does Seam even work in 1.7?

Comment: yes Seam 2.3.1 works fine with Java 1.7, are you using Eclipse? If so have you set the correct compiler? (Project > Properties > Java Compiler)

Comment: Using JBoss developer studio, yes I have set correct compiler and facets. Still having the above mentioned issue.